# Interpolating away from roads

Tags: grass-gis, interpolation

I have a raster layer of some roads and I want to interpolate it such that on the new layer, each cell has a value corresponding to how far it is from a road cell. The end result would look like a set of ridges (high values) for the roads, sloping away to low values as you move away from the roads.

What would be a suitable command for this processing? I believe 'interpolating' is the correct term but I am not certain as I am new to GIS.

Comment: This is often called the "[(Euclidean) distance](https://www.google.com/search?q=euclidean+distance+grid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" grid for the road features.  It is closely related to the [medial axis transform](https://www.google.com/search?q=euclidean+distance+grid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=medial+axis+transform). Although in some broad sense it could be construed as "interpolating" the roads, this would be an unusual use of the word, which means to fit new values between given values. Since all the distances on the road features themselves are zero, you are definitely not interpolating those!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a continuous surface, use r.grow.distance which generates a raster map containing distances to nearest raster features.

For an example, see
https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.grow.distance.html#distance-from-the-streams-network

[image]

Comment: Markus, thanks a million. That was exactly what I was looking for. In case any other real greenhorns see this, changing the colour table is necessary to produce a result like above.